# C++ Template - passing const value of type T by reference

Tags: c++, templates, reference, constants

I have a function with a template parameter T and would like to pass a value of type const T by reference.
The C++ compiler throws an error, (kind of) understandably so. Hence I was wondering if there exists a way to do this in a safe and concise way?

I created a very small example that reflects the issue I am having in my project.
(in my project the issue appears in a constant member function of some class, but from my experiments the issue should be "faithfully" reflected in the example below by use of a constant variable of int instead for simplicity's sake).

I am aware that I could theoretically use a separate template parameter "cT", but that would be horribly unsafe, as the caller of this function need not pass an object of "const T" as second argument ...
I also understand that I could simply refrain from using templates at all and just specify this for every type.
I was just wondering if what I am trying to achieve below can be done with templates.

Thanks and have a nice day! :)

```
template<typename T>
bool ContainsElement(std::list<T>& findList, const T& elem)
{
    for (auto& entry : findList)
    {
        if (entry == elem)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::list<int*> myList;
    const int testConst = 6;
    auto pointerToTestConst = &testConst;

    ContainsElement(myList, pointerToTestConst); // compiler screams
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Why are you trying to pass a pointer to int to a function that wants a reference? You can just pass `testConst`. Am I missing something?

Comment: The error message is either:
"template parameter is ambiguous"
or
"can't convert const int* to T &" (if I don't use a const int* but use this in a member function of some class instead)
However you can ignore the latter one

Comment: @JonReeves Practically you are absolutely right, however the type T need not necessarily be a pointer always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in incompatibility between pointers:

- `pointerToTestConst` is of type `const int*` - non-const pointer to const integer. Therefore `T=const int*`
- `myList` is of type `list<int*>`, deducing `T=int*`.

Since those types are not the same, compilation fails. Rightfully so, because `elem` would allow changing `testConst` if `T=int*`.

The issue manifests regardles you passing `elem` by (const) reference or value.

> horribly unsafe, as the caller of this function need not pass an object of "const T" as second argument

So what? They get a compiler error about the comparison. It is no more unsafe than your code right now. I would argue that a generic `ContainsElement` should not care what you pass to is as long as it compares equal to some element in the list, it is a match.

Of course STL already offers this for `std::find` and `std::ranges::find` which also does not care and it is not called unsafe because of it.

Comment: Thanks!
I figured there would not be a way to specify this.
I also appreciate your reference to std::find(), I was not aware of it. I always found it odd that std::list would not have a find method, but that is neat :)

Comment: @SalmarRignus Well, it is not that neat because `std::find` is `O(n)` and so other containers like `std::set` implement their own methods which are faster. There is also `std::binary_search`. I guess list doesn't have one because `std::find` is as fast it gets with lists.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of std::set and am even using it in this project ^^

I am currently implementing a model checker and for the actual (performance sensitive) model checking algorithm I don't need any contains operations on this list.
The contains operation on the list is only for acquiring other properties of the model.

If necessary e.g. to avoid quadratic complexity and obtain 2n instead, I resort to creating a temporary set with a copy of the list. :)

Answer (score 2):

To "normalize" the type for pointers and non-pointers, [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) may be used, finally your template still defines single `T` parameter:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
bool ContainsElement(std::list<T>& findList,
const std::conditional_t<
        std::is_pointer<T>::value,
        std::add_pointer_t<
                std::add_const_t<
                        std::remove_pointer_t<T>
                >
        >,
        std::add_const_t<T> 
>& elem)
{
    for (auto& entry : findList)
    {
        if (entry == elem)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

*Above example uses helper types with postfix `_t` introduced in C++14, for C++11, use `std::conditional::type`.*

It works for `std::list<int>` and `std::list<int*>`.

Of course in case of `std::list<int*>` it will check whether list contains exactly the same pointer address, not the pointed value.

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. So theoretically it can be done after all!

Comment: Yes, but this is just theoretical example. In real life you should use e.g: `bool contains = (std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), valueToFind) != list.end())` or something similar.

Comment: Oh absolutely. I already changed my code to use std::find(), which I was oblivious about.

Still, thanks for telling me about this possibility. One may never know when such tricks may come in handy, even when they generally are to be avoided.